# Where is the documentation for WebAssembly Heapf64.set

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I have a bit of code I'm trying to optimise and it uses `HEAPF64.set(jsArray, nativeArray)`

Where is the documentation for this function call?

Is it a copy function from jsArray to nativeArray or setting a pointer?

What is HEAPF64? If I already have a native buffer in WebAssembly can I set directly into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEAPF64 is one of several ArrayBufferView s that are created by the emscripten toolchain.  Others include HEAPU8 and HEAPU32.  They are all views of the same underlying WebAssembly memory buffer which is your C/C++ program's address space.

There is some documentation on how emscripten sets things up here: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#access-memory-from-javascript

Specifically the `.set` method you are asking about is documented here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set